# Type checking errors for PyCharm editor for datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pycharm, timedelta

I use PyCharm as an IDE and for the following piece of code which works fine PyCharm shows a highlighted error in the IDE. The IDE does not like the fact that I am adding a timedelta to a datetime object. However when I try it at the python prompt it works fine. Is there a correct way to do the following so that things type check correctly?

```
 >>> start = datetime.now()
 >>> td = timedelta(minutes=60)
 >>> type(td)
 <type 'datetime.timedelta'>
 >>> type(start)
 <type 'datetime.datetime'>
 >>> start + td
 datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 3, 19, 16, 23, 128354)
```

Comment: my pycharm does not complain about this .... what do you mean by "The IDE does not like the fact that I am adding a timedelta to a datetime object" ?

Comment: It show the code highlighted and when I do a mouse hover it shows a warning that it looked for datetime and found timedelta instead (something very similar)

Comment: What PyCharm version do you use? Your issue is not reproducible in 2017.2 and it seems that it was fixed in 2017.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your example what version of Python you are running, 2.x or 3.x? Regardless, did you import the necessary modules? e.g.

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
```

Comment: I am using python 2.7, and using the 2017 Pycharm CE